# How can I bind a component to a dynamic external state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I achieve the following data binding?

```js
const Component = ({state}) => (
  <div>
    {state.counter} // I want this to update every second.
  </div>
);

// Some dynamically updating data.
const myData = {
  counter: 0,
}

render(
  <Component state={myData} />,
  document.body
);

setInterval(() => {
  myData.counter++; // Simulate dynamic updates.
}, 1000);
```

I've tested React, but the DOM doesn't update because I don't want to manually force React to re-render.

Comment: You don't need to manually force it to re-render. If props changed in one component, it will re-render automatically. Just use the designed waterfall data-flow in React would be fine. So in this post, the situation is QA=> QB => QC, you are asking QC but the real problem may occur in QB or QA, so I guess this post needs more focus. Ask why not updated instead, with full code is preferred.

Comment: @keikai See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Labesx7/). The DOM doesn't update.

Comment: Why is this tagged `vue.js`?

Comment: @DecadeMoon I was thinking it would be possible to do in vue.js as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue supports this out of the box:

```js
const state = { counter: 0 }

setInterval(() => state.counter++, 1000)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: state
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ counter }}
</div>
```

> I've tested React, but the DOM doesn't update because I don't want to manually force React to re-render.

The framework needs to know when the data changes in order to re-render the view. Vue achieves this by transparently wrapping each property of the data object with reactive getters and setters so it can track changes to the object. React doesn't do this, instead you have to mutate data using methods like `setState` so React knows that something changed. I'm not very familiar with React, so I can't give you a React example.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the example! I will use Vue.js.